# Prove that the Riemann integral of f is 0

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

> Let $f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 \quad x\in\{\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{8}, \cdots \}\\0\quad \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$
>
> By considering the minorant and majorant step functions, show that the Reimann integral of $f$ on $[0,1]$ is $0$.

I’m having trouble finding a partition to use. I planned on partitioning the interval as follows: $[1,\frac{1}{2}) \cup \{\frac{1}{2}\} \cup (\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4})\cup \cdots$ but clearly this wouldn’t reach a closed bound at $0$ unless it was infinite.

Comment: My answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4095979/9754) would essentially answer this question too, with the minor modifications of the locations of the points. But a discrete collection of points with a single clustering point in the limit --- it's very similar. Do you see how to adjust my answer?

Comment: @davidlowryduda Thank you so much! I got it to work using ε/2^(n+1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partitions $P_n=\{k2^{-n}:k=0,\ldots 2^{n}\}$ will do the job. For example,

$$\begin{align}
L(P_n,f)&=\sum^{2^n}_{k=1}\inf\{f(x):(k-1)2^{-n}\leq x\leq k2^{-n}\}\frac{1}{2^n}=0
\\
U(P_n,f)&= \sum^{2^n}_{k=1}\sup\{f(x):(k-1)2^{-n}\leq x\leq k2^{-n}\}\frac{1}{2^n}=\frac{n}{2^n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0
\end{align}$$

The lower Darboux sum is simple since the $\inf\{f(x):(k-1)2^{-n}\leq x\leq k2^{-n}\}=0$ for each $1\leq k\leq 2^n$.

The upper Darboux sum is not too difficult to check. The partition $P_n$ contains the points $0,2^{-n},2^{-(n-1)}=2\cdot 2^{-n},\ldots, 2^{-2}=2^{n-2}2^{-n},\frac12=2^{n-1}2^{-n},1=2^n2^{-n}$. There are $n$ subintervals formed by the elements of $P_n$ that contain those points as endpoints; each subinterval has length $2^{-n}$. See if you can work out the details.

I hope this helps.